# Obtain CssScope value of a Blazor Component

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, asp.net-core-css-isolation

I have a Blazor server application that contains a component which generates a list of html paragraphs.

```html
<div class="text">
  @FormatText(Obj.Synposis)
</div>
```

using this simple function:

```cs
@functions 
{
  private MarkupString FormatText(string text)
  {
    var Result = string.Concat(text.Split('¶', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries | StringSplitOptions.TrimEntries).Select(e => $@"<p>{e}</p>"));

    return new MarkupString(Result);
  }
}
```

the corresponding component's css style contains this:

```css
  div.text > p {
    margin-bottom: 50rem;
    background-color: red;
  }
```

This issue is that the generate html string lacks the component's css scope value and therefore any style applied is ignored.

To make sure we're on the same page, the rendered css will contain this:

```css
  div.text > p[b-taj2ej35sx] {
    margin-bottom: 50rem;
    background-color: red;
  }
```

... and I would have to apply that css scope as `<p b-taj2ej35sx="">...` in FormatText() for the style to get applied. I need to obtain the string value "**b-taj2ej35sx**" somehow.

The question is:

1. can I (and how) find the component's css scope value? can I re-calculate the value myself (the code following **b-**)? then it would be just a matter of adding that to the `<p>` string
2. can I tell blazor to not apply css scoping for a single css element in the style sheet?
3. can I trick blazor somehow to fail to scope a css element? it already looks like the compiler failed to scope both `div.text` and `p` elements in that style rule

Comment: Is it possible that your `<div>` is somehow being detected as a child? Try adding `::deep` in front of your style declaration in the .css file and see if that resolves the issue.

Comment: Is this all in the same component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't need to do anything with the scope unique Id.

I'm assuming all your code is in the same component.

Here's my code that demonstrates what you've set out and works.  I've simplified it a little.

The key is to use `RenderFragments`.  The Razor compiler treats `MarkupString` as just that, and doesn't apply any CSS component magic to it.

`Index.razor` with the markup that should be generated.

```
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>


<div class="text">
    @GetFormattedText
</div>

@code {
    private string countries = "France, UK, Spain, Portugal";

    private RenderFragment GetFormattedText => (__builder) =>
    {
        var items = countries.Split(',', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries | StringSplitOptions.TrimEntries);
        foreach(var item in items)
        {
         <p>@item</p>   
        }
    };
}
```

`Index.razor.css`:

```css
div.text > p {
    margin-bottom: 5rem;
    background-color: red;
}
```

And the result:

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work this way. The razor compiler will automatically add the css scope attribute to all html tags in the .razor file, as shown in the image. But when I add html code via MarkupString,, the css scope attribute will not be added and the style fails.. Try @(new MarkupString("<p>France</p><p>Spain</p>")) instead of <p>France</p><p>Spain</p> which is essentially what my function FormatText("France¶Spain") does.

Comment: @hopperpl as your scoped styles include the scope attribute after compiling, you will need to use the ::deep operation to target the markupstring. `.text > ::deep p`

Comment: @hopperpl - correct, but it did get me on the same page as you!  I've updated my answer which I believe now works.

Comment: @BrianParker - I think the problem is how the Razor compiler transposes `MarkupString` into `RenderTreeBuilder` commands, and thus how the Renderer builds out the final html to it's virtual DOM.